yii2 imposible changed font family
I have an action to make a pdf and display it, the only thing I need is to give it a signature but I have not been able to change the font family in any way, at least not with renderpartial
My code
`public function actionGenerarPdf($id)
{
$model = Persona::findOne(['id' => $id]); // Asegúrate de tener esta función en tu controlador para encontrar el modelo por su ID.
    $searchModel = new DocumentoadjuntoSearch();
    $dataProvider = $searchModel->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams, 1, $model->id, 'Persona');

    // Buscar información laboral del usuario
    $informacionLaboralModel = Informacionlaboral::findAll(['idPersona' => $model->id]);

    // Buscar información de estudio del usuario
    $informacionEstudioModel = Informacionestudio::findAll(['idPersona' => $model->id]);

    // Buscar información de oficios
    $informacionOficiosModel = Informacionoficios::findAll(['idPersona' => $model->id]);




    $content = $this->renderPartial('print', [
        'model' => $model,
        'searchModel' => $searchModel,
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        'informacionLaboralModel' => $informacionLaboralModel,
        'informacionEstudioModel' => $informacionEstudioModel,
        'informacionOficiosModel' => $informacionOficiosModel,
    ]);

    $pdf = new Pdf([
        // set to use UTF8 encode only
        'mode' => Pdf::MODE_UTF8,

        // A4 paper format
        'format' => Pdf::FORMAT_A4,

        // portrait orientation
        'orientation' => Pdf::ORIENT_PORTRAIT,

        'filename' => 'Hoja de vida ' . $model->primerNombre . date("d M Y"),
        'content' => $content,
        'cssFile' => '@vendor/kartik-v/yii2-mpdf/src/assets/kv-mpdf-bootstrap.min.css',
        // 'cssInline' => '.firma{font-family: Pacifico, cursive; color:red;}',
        'cssInline' => '
        #firma{
            font-family: "Pacifico", cursive !important;
            font-size:44px !important;
            color:#ffff !important,
        }',
        'options' => ['title' => 'Krajee Report Title'],
        'methods' => [
            'SetTitle' => 'Hoja de vida',
            'SetSubject' => 'Generating PDF : ' . $model->primerNombre,
            'SetHeader' => ['Hoja de vida ||Generado el: ' . date("d M Y")],
            'SetFooter' => ['|Pagina {PAGENO}|'],
            'SetAuthor' => $model->primerNombre,
            'SetCreator' => $model->primerNombre,
            'SetKeywords' => 'Krajee, Yii2, Export, PDF, MPDF, Output, Privacy, Policy, yii2-mpdf',
            // 'SetFooter' => [
            //     '<i style="font-family: Pacifico, cursive;">Firma: ' . $model->primerNombre . '</i>'
            // ],
            'SetFooter' => ['<i style="text-align:end; font-weight:blod; font-family:"Pacifico"; font-size:25px; font-style: italic;">' . $model->primerNombre . '</i>'],

        ]
    ]);



    return $pdf->render();

    // return   $this->render('print', [
    //     'model' => $model,
    //     'searchModel' => $searchModel,
    //     'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    //     'informacionLaboralModel' => $informacionLaboralModel,
    //     'informacionEstudioModel' => $informacionEstudioModel,
    //     'informacionOficiosModel' => $informacionOficiosModel,
    // ]);
}

}
`
Is there any way to make it easy? I can use the font family in the view and it works, but if I render normally, that is, using render() and not renderpartial()
`

primerNombre ?>

`
